# ¿Sumar numeros Automaticamente en HTML?

Tags: html

Necesito ayuda en HTML, estoy elaborando una pagina y necesito ingresar 2 numeros en cuadro de texto e imprimir automaticamente el resultado en un nuevo cuadro de texto.

Comment: Bienvenido, a tu pregunta le hace falta mucho contenido, te adelanto que solo con HTML no lo vas a lograr, requieres de algún lenguaje de programación, recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar el evento **change**, el codigo de abajo es cuando se espera una suma como resultado.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="numero1">Numero 1</label>
<input type="text" id="numero1" onchange="sumar();"><br>

<label for="numero2">Numero 2</label>
<input type="text" id="numero2" onchange="sumar();"><br>

<label for="resultado">Resultado</label>
<input type="text" id="resultado">

<script>
    // si la respuesta que se espera es sumar
    function sumar(){
        var numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1').value;
        var numero2 = document.getElementById('numero2').value;

        if(numero1!=='' && numero2!==''){
            var suma = parseInt(numero1)+parseInt(numero2);
            document.getElementById('resultado').value = suma;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, pero por favor evitemos responder a preguntas tan mal planteadas, que no muestran avance o intento alguno, ya que terminen cerradas y solo podría traerte votos negativos

Comment: Buena observación